# How do you turn a dict of lists into a list of dicts with all combinations?

Tags: python

Basically what I am looking for is the equivalent of `itertools.product` but for `dict`s.

For example, say I want to test a function for all combinations of its keyword arguments, I would like to pass lists of permissible values for each keyword argument and then get back a list of dicts.

```
kwargs_options = {"debug": ["on", "off"], 
                  "locale":["de_DE", "en_US", "fr_FR"]
```

expected ouput:

```
[{'debug': 'on', 'locale': 'de_DE'},
 {'debug': 'on', 'locale': 'en_US'},
 {'debug': 'on', 'locale': 'fr_FR'},
 {'debug': 'off', 'locale': 'de_DE'},
 {'debug': 'off', 'locale': 'en_US'},
 {'debug': 'off', 'locale': 'fr_FR'}]
```

In order to have a similar API to `itertools.product` this should return an iterator, which can then be wrapped with a call to `list(...)` if desired.

Example call:

```
list(dictproduct(kwargs_options}))
```

This is similar to [Combinations from dictionary with list values using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873654/combinations-from-dictionary-with-list-values-using-python) but returns a list of two-element dicts rather than two single-element dicts.

Comment: Self-answering is fine, but *the question* still needs to be on-topic. This question, without the answer for context, is unanswerable.

Comment: Including an actual concrete example, with sample inputs and expected output would go a long way towards making this question clearer.

Comment: Apologies, I came up with the answer when looking at another question (which I referenced) and wanted to share it. So I rushed in the question. I have now made it more clear.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I have come up with:

```
from itertools import product

def dictproduct(dct):
    for t in product(*dct.itervalues()):
        yield dict(zip(dct.iterkeys(), t))
```

which gives us

```
>>> list(dictproduct({"debug":["on", "off"], "locale":["de_DE", "en_US", "fr_FR"]}))
[{'debug': 'on', 'locale': 'de_DE'},
 {'debug': 'on', 'locale': 'en_US'},
 {'debug': 'on', 'locale': 'fr_FR'},
 {'debug': 'off', 'locale': 'de_DE'},
 {'debug': 'off', 'locale': 'en_US'},
 {'debug': 'off', 'locale': 'fr_FR'}]
```

This can also be used to efficiently call a function with all combinations of keyword arguments:

```
def kwproduct(**kwargs):
    return dictproduct(kwargs)

def f(x, y):
    return 10*x + y

for kwargs in kwproduct(x=[1,2], y=[3,4,5]):
    print "f({x},{y})={z}".format(z=f(**kwargs), **kwargs)
```

output:

```
f(1,3)=13
f(2,3)=23
f(1,4)=14
f(2,4)=24
f(1,5)=15
f(2,5)=25
```

The benefit of `kwproduct` over `dictproduct` is that you don't need to create a `dict` but it obviously limits you to use valid argument names as keys.

Comment: Downvoting question, upvoting answer.