# Django fixture with all possible combinations?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, fixtures

I am trying to test a statistics function, which counts what type of objects I have in my database. For this I would like to create at least one instance of each possible combination of model fields. Random test data requires a lot of test objects to make sure all possible combinations are met.

Here is a shortened example from one of my models:

```
class Member(models.Model)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    name = models.CharField()
    balance = models.IntegerField()
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Class Division(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
```

This is how I'm doing it right now using django_dynamic_fixture:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django_dynamic_fixture import G
from members.models import Member

class StatisticsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        for is_active in [True, False]:
            for balance in [-100, 0, 100]:
                for division in Division.objects.all()
                    G(Member, is_active=is_active, balance=balance, division=division)
```

But this looks pretty bad and is hard to read. Is there a simpler way with better to read code to create all possible combinations of properties of an object?

I'm open to different test data generators as long as they work nicely with Python 3 and Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sara's answer is a good step forward, but I am still not satisfied by the code readability, so I am answering my own question.

```
variants = {
    'is_active': [True, False],
    'balance': [-100, 0, 100],
    'division': list(Division.objects.all())
}

names = sorted(variants)
products = [dict(zip(names, prod)) for prod in it.product(*(variants[name] for name in names))]

for combination in products:
    G(Member, **combination)
```

Now anyone wanting to change this test can easily see which property is tested with which values. Thanks go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870807/how-do-you-turn-a-dict-of-lists-into-a-list-of-dicts-with-all-combinations) q&a for the dict solution.

Comment: There's a `SyntaxError` in your code at `[*Division.objects.all()]`. You can't unpack a list within a list. You're right. I've a very narrow view.

Comment: @xyres `Division.objects.all()` returns a `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` which can be unpacked like this. But since I'm the person talking about readability: `list(Division.objects.all()` is better to understand. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No, `[*Division.objects.all()]` is a `SyntaxError`. It has got nothing to with Django `QuerySet`, because `SyntaxError` means that it is not a valid Python syntax. You can't use `*` to unpack something anywhere other than while passing arguments to a function. You can try it in a Python shell and see what I mean.

Comment: @xyres Could it be you did not realize my question is about Python 3? Because it is and in Python 3 `[*[1, 2]]` is not a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```python
import itertools

combinations = list(itertools.product(*[[True, False], [-100, 0, 100]]))
for division in Division.objects.all():
    for is_active, balance in combinations:
        G(Member, is_active=is_active, balance=balance, division=division)
```

---

Update:

```
import itertools

combinations = list(itertools.product([True, False], [-100, 0, 100], Division.objects.all()))
for is_active, balance, division in combinations:
    G(Member, is_active=is_active, balance=balance, division=division)
```

Comment: Here - `product(*[[True, False], [-100, 0, 100]])` - why are you passing the arguments in a list and then unpacking the list? Just `product([True, False], [-100, 0, 100])` works fine. No need to convert the generator to a `list`, either. Generators are much more efficient than plain lists.

Comment: Also, you can further improve the answer by putting the `division` objects in `combinations` as well.

Comment: Yes, good idea, and I will write an update, as for your first question, I'd say either way works since the function doesn't specify the input length: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Hm, I think this is better to read, but still not satisfying. Now I'd build a long list of values with no relation to their meaning, but their order. That's fine for 3 properties, but if you have 10 properties it would be better to have a dict where the values are connected to a label.

Comment: Also I was hoping to find this as a ready-made feature in some test data/fixture generator ;)

Comment: If we stick with this approach (which is sensible, albeit not what I was hoping) I'd mark this question a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873654/combinations-from-dictionary-with-list-values-using-python).

Comment: @vollkorn A dict id going to be less efficient. And you don't need to make a `list` here because `itertools.product` will give you a generator which is far more efficient than either a list or a dict. But leaving that aside, why do you think that labelling the properties is a better idea? Are you going to access the properties later? You don't mention that in your original question. Anyway, this actually answers your question - `Is there a simpler way ... to create all possible combinations of properties ...?`, whether you're satisfied or not.

Comment: @xyres It's about readability. In my test case I have 8 properties. Using this approach means I have all the values for these 8 properties without any context inside the `itertools.product` and when you want to change something you need to look at a different line, count which place to modify and then count again to find that place in the code line with the values. So yes, a dict might be slower, but much better to read. Code readability is my main concern: `with better to read code`

Comment: @vollkorn `"In my test case I have 8 properties. Using this approach means I have all the values for these 8 properties without any context"` yeah, that's alright. But that's nowhere in your original question. Your question says `"Django fixture with all possible combinations?"`, so does the description and this answer gives you that. If you want a dict, you are free to ask another question.

Comment: @xyres If your view is this narrow I already answered my own question by posting it, because it has a working solution with for loops. But I stated clearly that I wanted a readable way. Well, no reason to discuss this any further here.