# All combinations of of an object with array values for its keys

Tags: javascript, data-structures, combinatorics

I'm essentially looking for the JavaScript equivalent of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873734/411954), specifically in the first format provided in that response.

In other words, given the object:

```
let variants = {
  debug : ["on", "off"],
  locale : ["de_DE", "en_US", "fr_FR"],
}
```

I'd like a function that returns:

```
[{debug: 'on', locale: 'de_DE'},
 {debug: 'on', locale: 'en_US'},
 {debug: 'on', locale: 'fr_FR'},
 {debug: 'off', locale: 'de_DE'},
 {debug: 'off', locale: 'en_US'},
 {debug: 'off', locale: 'fr_FR'}]
```

The solution I'm looking for should be unaware of what keys are in the input object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this ES6 function:

```js
function combinations(variants) {
    return (function recurse(keys) {
        if (!keys.length) return [{}];
        let result = recurse(keys.slice(1));
        return variants[keys[0]].reduce( (acc, value) =>
            acc.concat( result.map( item => 
                Object.assign({}, item, { [keys[0]]: value }) 
            ) ),
            []
        );
    })(Object.keys(variants));
}                     

// Sample data
let variants = {
  debug : ["on", "off"],
  locale : ["de_DE", "en_US", "fr_FR"],
};
// Result
console.log(combinations(variants));
```

#### Explanation

The main function gets the array of keys (with `Object.keys`) of the given object, and passes it to a recursive function (`recurse`).

This inner function first checks if there are keys, if not the recursion ends, and an array with a single, empty object is returned.

In all other cases, the function is called recursively with one less key.

The result from that recursive call is then iterated (with `result.map()`) and for each entry, a new object is generated that has one more property -- the current key (i.e. the first from the array of keys) and the current value for that key. The values are iterated over with `reduce()`, and the above is repeated for every such value. These sub-results are concatenated with `acc.concat()` into a larger array that is returned to the caller.

Comment: Bravo. I knew `reduce` was going to be part of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var debugCombs = [];
for(var debugVal in debug) {
    for(var localeVal in locale) {
         debugCombs.push({debug: debugVal, locale: localeVal});
    }
}
```

I hope this is fairly self explanatory: iterate through each list and push it all to an array.

Comment: Should have made my question clearer -- the solution can't be aware of what keys are in the original object.